# Driving a 15 KHz RGB monitor

Tags: screen

I'm interested in the prospect of using a RP to run MAME in a real arcade cabinet.

The easy way is to replace the cabinet's monitor. However I'd really like the authenticity of keeping the original 15Khz RGB monitor.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how one could drive such a monitor from a RP?

**Edit**: On standard PC hardware, this is a pretty well understood area. Some graphics cards can be underclocked to 15Hz. Get one of these cards, get suitable drivers, and use something like [AdvMAME](http://advancemame.sourceforge.net/). The challenge with RP is that it hasn't an interface these graphics cards could use.

Comment: Very intersting mod. I found this.. http://www.mmmonkey.co.uk/console/other/rgb2vga.htm I have no idea what is going on but maybe it will help you? Has the monitor got video in ? ntsc/pal/ scart or something? and this? http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W1MfqbyGamE

Comment: Thanks ppumkin. The first link is conversion in the wrong direction: upscaling a lo-res input to VGA. The second link is the right kind of thing. Is there a way to hook an RPi to a PCI/AGP/whatever video card?

Comment: I don't think you will get close to handling PCI or AGP im a afraid. Maybe ISA but you will have to do some mega driver code and software will be rubbish. Try and keep looking for CGA to VGA hardware solutions. Just need to reverse the process.

Comment: If the 15 KHz monitor uses television timings, I would think you could use the pi's composite output, with a composite to RGB/Sync converter circuit, if the monitor doesn't already have that - though of course composite will not be as sharp due to the limited color bandwidth.  What would be ideal would be some sort of HDMI-to-SCART device.

Comment: This question relates to [What are the pros and cons of connecting to a VGA monitor?](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/484/141). My [answer](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/505/141) has some information which *might* help. Even then you are going to have to be very careful about setting up the timings. I know that xorg used to be very flexible in v & h timings, frequency and blanking timings etc, but I don't know if *mame* has similar flexibility.

Comment: I did this for my old arcade machine but with a PC of course. wire mapping was pretty easy. AdvMAME is really good for setting video output to 15Khz as well and easy to get set up in linux. Wish I could provide some more info. Good luck!

Comment: @Bryan Could you post an answer as how you did it with a PC? Maybe there is "solution in your madness"

Comment: @ppumkin it's well understood on normal PC hardware. I'll add something to the question to summarise this.

Comment: necro-comment: the new [pi zero](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/raspberry-pi-zero/) has a composite video out, which seems to be much more compatible with RGB

Comment: All the Pis have had composite out. It's not really an adequate substitute for RGB.

Answer (score 13):

**Firstly**, since the Raspberry Pi doesn't have an RGB out, you will need an ACTIVE (with a chip to logically convert Digital to Analog) HDMI to VGA. I use one of these on my RPi and it works great- for older VGA monitors.. but yet again the price is going up...

[image]

[I bought this HDMI to VGA from ebay](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/270954984313?ssPageName=STRK:MEWNX:IT&_trksid=p3984.m1439.l2649#ht_5230wt_952)

- *I have Model B, I do not know if it will work on Model A because of power constraints.*
- *Also you have to [read this](http://elinux.org/RPi_Screens#RGB_analog.2FVGA). Apparently using and inline active converter can cause long term issues with out tweaking something on the board....*
- *UPDATE: In revision C boards and older the power constraint is no longer an issue*

So you can get [this one suggested by Mark Booth](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Mini-HDMI-1-3-Digital-Signal-to-VGA-Audio-Analog-Video-Converter-Full-HD-1080P-/270989206433?pt=UK_Computing_CablesConnectors_RL&hash=item3f183723a1#ht_6858wt_952) if you are concerned about the issues described in the wiki.

---

**Secondly**, you will need to convert from VGA to CGA. Something like this bad boy! (known as a  GBS-8100)

[image]

You can buy it on [ebay for not that cheap.](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Video-Converter-PCB-VGA-CGA-CVBS-S-Video-TV-/170418508880#ht_2811wt_905). But maybe it can help you develop some other mod along the same line?

---

Some **additional references** that might help you with alternative home brew solutions.

This [looks like a converter](http://www.pc-extras.com/prods/advgac.html) but not sure if it actually does anything in processing the signal to the correct format.

Again another way to take [CGA into Scart](http://electroschematics.com/377/cga-scart-adapter/).. but maybe some reverse can be applied?

Comment: This is unlikely to help, as the pi does not have VGA output.

Comment: With that kind of attitude - No its not going to help anybody.. I edited my answer- because I forgot I use a DVI to VGA thinga ma doo daa. Problem solved. not cheap though

Comment: Yea cool- makes sense i started from the back and worked forward.. Your edit does make it more logical in thought. Thanks :)

Comment: yea - I found my purchased one and linked it instead as its the one I use and i know it works. Also the RPI wiki says these "Chinese" ones should be OK- but I cannot find how much current they need anywhere.

Comment: @Mark no, the basic technical issue remains in thst it is unclear if results would be satisfactory after the additional conversion.  More importantly, after the cost of two converters is added, most of the advantages of a raspberry pi vs other low cost (or recycled) platforms are negated.

Comment: I strongly agree with what you say Chris. We seem to want to use Raspberry Pi for everything but we do not need to. End of the day the answer is "correct" and the devices do what they are specified to do and reach the end goal.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - That's an entirely different argument. We have no idea if slim is constrained by cost or just wants to do this for the fun if it. This answer does now address your original concern, anything else is beyond the scope of this question. Feel free to post a better answer, if you have one.

Comment: Can I ask a stupid question? Isn't the composite output an analog RGB output?

Comment: Technically No. Composite is a "smoosh" of RGB and Luminance, multiplexed into an analog sygnal using a standard such as NTSC or PAL/SECAM that can be decoded "unshmooshed" in the TV for example. You can convert composite to RGB using active components.. but the quality is worse than DVI to VGA

Comment: @AlexChamberlain this is the pity. It "feels" to me as if there must be a TV-res RGB signal somewhere in the signal chain, but by the time it reaches a well-known output socket, it's been encoded into composite.

Comment: @Slim you are correct in both your assumptions. To get Composite you need RGB - But its done using hardware inside the BCM chip- so you cannot hook it in any level of software. If there was VGA output, or VGA pin outs it would make life allot easier for some people

Answer (score 0):

As posted you need hdmi to vga then vga to rgb downscaler
fuller details also here
https://celso.io/tech-stuff/2012/12/17/connecting-a-raspberry-pi-to-an-old-15khz-arcade-monitor.html

> Connecting a Raspberry Pi to an old 15Khz Arcade Monitor Dec 17, 2012
> The Raspberry Pi has been used all over the world as an excellent
> emulator box to resuscitate old arcade machines, but with moderate
> success.
>
> You see, if you’re a truly arcade aficionado like me, then you’ll aim
> for perfection. And perfection means you’ll use the jamma connector
> and the old 15Khz CRT instead of a more modern retro fitted VGA
> monitor like most people opt to do.
>
> Old arcade CRT sets can only accept 15Khz horizontal frequencies using
> separate RGB signals and a sync line (well, not quite, there are 25
> Khz monitors too but they’re uncommon). Ultimarc has an excellent
> article about arcade monitors if you want more details.
>
> The problem with that is the Raspberry only outputs HDMI digital video
> or 15Khz composite video (no RGB), so there’s no easy / cheap solution
> to get pure 15Khz RGB signals out of the Pi to feed the arcade CRT.
>
> You could try to demodulate the composite video into RGB signals but
> that’s complex and expensive, and you’d lose a lot of information,
> picture would be poor.
>
> You could easily get a cheap HDMI to VGA active decoder on eBay or
> Amazon, and most work fine, but VGA signals are 31Khz and, even if
> they weren’t, you’d still need a level adapter / sync fix circuit
> (this article explains it).
>
> So, at Codebits VI, as part of the Hardware Den space initiatives, we
> restored a few old arcades, keeping the old controls, jamma connector
> and CRT monitors, and using the Raspberry Pi as the brains for
> emulation in partnership with the The Arcade Man. Did it work? Hell
> yes, here’s proof:
>
> So here’s how we did it.
>
> [image: https://celso.io/assets/connecting-a-raspberry-pi-to-an-old-15khz-arcade-monitor-2.jpg]
>
> Power Suppy
>
> Everything is powered by the original Arcade power supply. These are
> some powerful power supplies I tell you, they can output 5V, -5V and
> 12V and up to 15A. You don’t need this much but heck, it’s already
> there, it’s built to last, it’s powerful and very stable, so we used
> it.
>
> We stripped down a few USB to Mini USB and Micro USB cords and used
> them to connect the power supply pins to the Mini USB amp and the
> Raspberry Pi. Make sure you’re using the 5V (not the minus 5V) pin
> otherwise you may damage your electronics.
>
> [image]
> HDMI to VGA
>
> We wanted the best possible video quality so video composite was out.
> We bought a cheap HDMI to VGA decoder at Amazon. You can find several
> brands available (look at eBay too), they shouldn’t cost more than
> 10€. Read the comments before you buy one, they often mention the
> Raspberry Pi. We tried 3 different brands, they all worked. These are
> active decoders, meaning they have a small chipset inside and they’re
> able to decode the digital HDMI protocol and produce the analog VGA
> signals on the other end. A lot of people are buying these to connect
> their rPIs to normal VGA monitors.
>
> The problem with these small decoders is in the details. Some of them
> work with a wide range of resolutions, some of them don’t. Some
> require a boost on the HDMI lines. Some provide EDID capabilities,
> some don’t (or they’re wrong). So you need to spend some time tweaking
> your RaspberryPi config in order to get the best results first.
>
> This is our config.txt config:

```
hdmi_drive=2
# defines the HDMI type CEA/DMT, 0 will use the preferred group reported by the edid.
config_hdmi_boost=6
hdmi_ignore_edid=0xa5000080
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=9
disable_overscan=1

#
# These are optional
#
# hdmi_force_hotplug=1
# hdmi_ignore_hotplug=1

arm_freq=1000
core_freq=500
sdram_freq=500
over_voltage=6
```

> arm_freq=1000 core_freq=500 sdram_freq=500 over_voltage=6 The most
> important settings here are the hdmi_ignore_edid which makes your
> RaspberryPi ignore edid and allows you to use pretty much any VGA
> resolution (this is important for game emulation) and hdmi_group (you
> want to use DMT).
>
> Our Raspberry Pi is also overclocked (this is important too, depending
> on the games you wish to play).
>
> VGA to RGB downscaler
>
> VGA gives us 31Khz analog video, but we need 15Khz. On the “normal” PC
> emulation scene this is a well known (and solved) problem. Solution 1:
> Some graphic cards allow you to set 15Khz resolutions on the VGA
> connector which work great with Linux and Advmame or you can use
> Soft15Khz under Windows. Solution 2: You buy a dedicated 15Khz
> graphics card for arcade usage, Ultimarc sells the ArcadeVGA, very
> popular.
>
> Problem is, you can’t connect a graphics card to the Raspberry Pi and,
> although the on board Broadcom chip supports them, there’s no way to
> get 15Khz resolutions through the decoded HDMI, then modulated VGA
> (probably fixed at 31Khz by the crappy Chinese adaptor).
>
> The only way would be to use video downscaling. This part was hard to
> solve. We knew we had to downscale our 31Khz VGA signals to 15Khz RGB
> lines and this is no easy task, it requires powerful video algorithms
> and heavy processing using dedicated chips. Professional equipments to
> do this job usually cost hundreds of Euros (or more).
>
> So we though we’d go through the old underground forums and dedicated
> pages for arcade parts in the hunt for a solution. And we found it.
>
> Our pick is the GBS 8100. This beautiful piece of hardware takes VGA
> input at 31Khz, downscales the video and is able to output it at 15Khz
> over RGBS pins (which can be connected directly to the arcade CRT
> board, cable included), VGA db9, RCA composite video or S-Video.
> Furthermore it has an OSD menu system and you can calibrate
> brightness, contrast, video offsets and other details. Requires 5V to
> operate. And it costs approximately $30.
>
> They are hard to find. We found two stores with stock and they both
> sent us working units within a few days with great customer service.
> They are:
>
> [image: Digital Systems Design (UK based) eBay (HK based store) Photo]
>
> USB Keyboard adapter
>
> The best way to connect your arcade controls to your Raspberry Pi
> (including the coin mech) is by using a USB device that adapts the
> switches on the joysticks and buttons to normal keyboard keys. From
> the software point of view, your controls will show up as a normal HID
> USB keyboard.
>
> There are several adapters available. We recommend these:
>
> I-Pac J-Pac The I-Pac is the best choice for this job but it will
> require you to desolder the JAMMA wires and connect them to the device
> inputs. If you go for the J-Pac then you can just connect the JAMMA
> adapter to it and it should work, but you won’t be using the VGA stuff
> (it’s made for 15Khz graphics cards, see above), so it’s a waste of
> money and functionality.
>
> This project on Kickstarter does pretty much the same, should be an
> interesting option when it’s available.
>
> [image: MG 7475]
>
> Mini USB Amp
>
> The Raspberry Pi sound output can’t be used directly with the cabinet
> speakers, you’ll need an audio amp first. We bought a pair of HP USB
> mini speakers, connected the main speaker’s USB cable to the arcade
> power supply and the rPi audio output. Then we used the cable to the
> second speaker to connect it to the cabinet speaker. Works fine.
>
> Photos or it didn’t happen
>
> Here are some photos of the whole thing.
>
> [image: ![2012 11 16 20 11 25]
>
> [image: NewImage]
>
> For left to right, Rob Bishop (Raspberry Pi foundation), Me and Luis
> Sobral (The Arcade Man).
>
> Conclusion
>
> This setup works flawlessly and we’re very happy with it. Picture
> quality is great and all things together, Raspberry Pi, HDMI to VGA
> adapter, VGA to CGA downscaler, USB controls adapter and Mini Amp, are
> under the 100€ mark. Add 70-90€ for an old working cabinet (which you
> can find at local warehouses from old arcade distributors) and a few
> more euros for some nice vinyls, buy a few damaged buttons /
> joysticks, and you’ve got yourself a fully working arcade cabinet for
> about 250€. Not bad.
>
> Many thanks to The Arcade Man for providing the old cabinets, painting
> and restoring them with new controls and vinyls, great job (also, read
> about the Sega Rally project he did with the Artica guys). Thanks to
> Rob Bishop and the Raspberry Pi Foundation for the support and for
> being with us at Codebits this year, it was awesome. Thanks to all the
> volunteers and Codebits participants too.
>
> The Raspberry is a wonderful retro gaming emulation machine. We’re
> using Advanced Mame for arcade games and Advance Menu for browsing the
> game library and menus. Right now we have a self configuring
> environment, the system boots in a nice, black minimalist menu
> sub-system, reads the roms on a special disk partition, then you can
> browse and chose your game using the cabinet controls, fool proof. A
> lot of roms work at full speed including great games like Shinobi,
> Megaman, Pang, R-Type, DoDonPachi, Bubble Bobble and many others. This
> was accomplished by a combination of overcooking, Advance Mame
> compilation and optimisation options, sound settings, optimal screen
> resolutions, and a lot of configuration tweaks.
>
> The system is also running Amiga and C64 games in full screen, using
> the same menu system.
>
> I’m now cleaning the code and scripts, and documenting some stuff too.
> Next post will be an URL to a fully bootable, read to use, SD card
> image for your Raspberry Pi and all sources and code on my Github repo
> too, so stay tuned.
>
> About me hello at celso dot io

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/121848)