# Nano USB Wireless and HDMI to VGA

Tags: hardware, usb, wireless, hdmi

I just have a few questions about the components I'm buying to work along side the Raspberry Pi. I'm not a hardware guy, mostly software so I'm not entirely sure if this would work.

I don't have an HDMI TV or monitor so I was thinking of getting this [HDMI Male to VGA cable](http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/HDMI-Gold-Male-VGA-HD-15-Cable-6ft-1-8M-/330611638974?pt=AU_Electronics_Accessories_Wires_Cables&hash=item4cf9fd42be#ht_2523wt_1143), any ideas whether this will work?

I'm also planning on getting a [Nano USB Wireless adaptor/dongle](http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/Nano-USB-Wireless-N-802-11n-Mini-WiFi-Adaptor-Dongle-/170705004280?pt=AU_Components&hash=item27becfa6f8#ht_3723wt_1123) because I don't have a long enough ethernet cable and wireless is much easier for me.

I'm living in Melbourne so it's harder and more expensive to ship things from the US. If anyone has some feedback on these extras, I'd like to know before I buy them (although they're not that expensive so I'd be happy to get them and try them out).

Also, would I be able to use a Kindle charger to power the Raspberry Pi?

**UPDATE: I bought it and it works fine, I just had to use an automated script to install it!**

Comment: Please only ask a single question at once, otherwise it makes it very difficult to disentangle answers which only deal with parts of your 'question'.

Comment: Also, in your 'update' you don't specify what you bought which worked. We have to infer that you meant the wifi adapter, since the other devices shouldn't need an install script, but not everyone might know that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that cable will work. Have a look at the answers to this [question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/222/can-a-simple-cable-convert-hdmi-output-to-vga) for more info. The cable you linked to appears to be a passive cable and the Pi requires an active adapter/cable.

The wifi adapter looks like it will work. It is listed on the [verified peripherals list](http://elinux.org/RPi_VerifiedPeripherals) as working for others.

Likewise the kindle charger is listed on the verified peripherals list so should work. Though it is not listed as outputting a fiull 1.0 amp. so I would be a little leary, as power supply problems are the source of many problems with keyboards, wifi dongles and other peripherals.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply! Thanks for the info, I'll look into using an HDMI to VGA converter rather than a cable. 

For the power supply, I have a Lifetrons adapter with two USB ports on it, providing 5v although I'm not sure of the amperage but I've been using it to charge my phone, tablet, etc. I assume that would work with the RPi and a Micro USB cable?

Comment: Your power adapter should have the output amperage either on a sticker or molded into the plastic case, but it sounds like you should be okay.

Comment: It has a 1 amp maximum.. Will that be okay?

Comment: Assuming you only power the Pi with it you should be fine. If you end up using a USB hub you should get a powered hub to avoid power issues.

Comment: I'll probably get one of those later, or I'll look around for one, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The HDMI to VGA cable is almost certainly a passive cable (just wires) that relies on the device with the HDMI connector to be able to output analogue VGA signals when it detects that this cable is plugged in.

There is no standard for this as far as I know, and the Raspberry Pi certainly wouldn't support it.

From the advert itself:

> Please note(very important):
>
> - Not all of devices with HDMI or VGA interface is able to use this cable.
> - Analog signal and digital signal are hard to transfer.
> - It only fits High Definition Player, converter is needed when connect the PC and TV.
> - Please make sure that you understand how to use this cable before you purchase.
>
> So. please check your devices carefully before you place order.

You may also like to read [my answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/505/141) to [What are the pros and cons of connecting to a VGA monitor?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/484/141)