# HDMI to VGA converter

Tags: raspbian, hdmi

I am connected raspberry pi 2 model b HDMI to VGA converter cable to my Desktop VGA card.But in monitor first 10 seconds it will displays the process and then screen will some red scratches coming after 10 seconds and then total screen will not coming. (I think my VGA cable is very long that's why it is not coming or another problem)

Comment: The only way to diagnosis the problem is to connect the Pi via HDMI cable to and HDMI monitor or TV. How long is the cable you are using?

Comment: my cable length is : 6 foot; 15-pin male to male VGA; Heavy duty Cable  actually i am using HDMI to VGA converter and then VGA converter to System VGA cable then monitor is connected

Comment: And how long is the adapter

Comment: may be 2 to 3 meters

Comment: I don't think that's long enough to cause issues, provided appropriate boosts are set in boot.txt and resolutions are modestly set. Don't expect 4k resolution on a cable that long.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you use the right converter? It sounds like you are using two converter?
Why not just find a VGA to HDMI cable or a DVI to HDMI cable? Not all converters work on Raspberry.
[Can a simple cable convert HDMI output to VGA?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/222/can-a-simple-cable-convert-hdmi-output-to-vga?s=10|0.2561)
Try to look at the link, there are some explanation about the type of converters.

Comment: Actually i am used (Raspberrypi kit--->HDMI---->(converter)--->VGA(female)---->VGA(Male)----->(system cable)------>VGA(male)------>vga female of system monitor this way i am connected sir

Comment: Why not try to buy one single cable?