# VGA Mode on RaspPi

Tags: pi-3, hdmi, video

Reading the `config.txt` [docs](https://elinux.org/RPiconfig#Video_mode_options), I found this:

> These values are valid if hdmi_group=1 (CEA)
>
> hdmi_mode=1    VGA

Does this make the output on my HDMI port be VGA? I have a cable that with a VGA and an HDMI ports, but no converter. Would I be able to use a VGA monitor with that cable and the Pi outputting VGA? Or is this something completely different?

Comment: That you "have a cable that with a VGA and an HDMI ports, but no converter" sounds unusual. Normally a cable will have the same kind of connectors, both HDMI or both VGA, unless it is a converter cable. There are two main types of converter cables. One type converts electrically similar but physically different connectors such as a gender mender or a USB cable with type A on one end and type B on the other. Other type converts electrically different connectors such as an HDMI to VGA converter cable. HDMI and VGA use connectors that are physically different and electrically different.

Comment: This cable [here](https://pt.aliexpress.com/item/LEORY-1-5M-HDMI-VGA-Cable-Male-To-Male-HD-1080P-Video-Converter-Adapter-Cable-Connector/32818227416.html) doesn't convert, you need a graphics card that can output VGA signal through the HDMI connector (or vice-versa, im not sure)

Comment: The title uses the phrase "Video Converter Adapter" however the actual images do not appear to have a VGA/HDMI converter. The cables I have seen and used for VGA and HDMI conversion have a fairly large connector at the VGA end which encloses the converter hardware. This cable you linked to appears to have just a standard VGA male connector. And the price seems to be too low at $4 as if it is just a cable. Prices for VGA/HDMI converters are around $10 on US Amazon.

Comment: @RichardChambers Exactly. I made the mistake of buying it, but it's just a sucker's knock-off.

Comment: Oh my. I am sorry to hear that. I hope you can return it for a refund or perhaps register a complaint. Good luck on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in the documentation you linked:

> `hdmi_mode` defines **screen resolution** in CEA or DMT format

In this case, [VGA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_Graphics_Array) would seem to be referring to the *resolution*, rather than the VGA connector. As noted by Wikipedia:

> Through widespread adoption, the term has also come to mean either an analog computer display standard, the 15-pin D-subminiature VGA connector, or **the 640×480 resolution characteristic of the VGA hardware.**

---

Converting HDMI to VGA is actually rather more complex than just flipping a setting, as HDMI is a digital protocol and VGA is analogue. You typically need an active converter, like [this](https://thepihut.com/products/raspberry-pi-hdmi-to-vga-convertor), to make it all work properly.

**See also:** [Can a simple cable convert HDMI output to VGA?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/222/58316)