# Micro HDMI to VGA MOnitor for Raspberry PI 4b

Tags: boot-issues

I'm using a Raspberry Pi 4b. I want to use my Acer LCD Monitor Version G206HQL  bd, which uses VGA or DVI inputs. I am also using a Micro HDMI to VGA adapter for my RPI to communicate with the monitor, but when the input type to the monitor is switched to VGA and I attempt to begin the boot up process for the Pi (using NOOBS at first but eventually Raspian) the screen on the monitor simply says No Cable Connected. The raspberry illustrations do not come to screen, and the boot is not output to the monitor. If anyone knows how to fix this issue, please respond.

Comment: Ah let me see.  In my Rpi3 days I did use HDMI to DVI/VGA adapter for my non HDMI monitor.  But now there might be a problem with Rpi4B which, I think, defaults to HDMI monitor.  When you plug in your HDMI monitor, even without power on, Rpi4B would supply logic circuit 5V power to HDMI to find it config to prepare for display as soon a power is on.  I noticed that the /boot.config.txt no longer has non HDMI device tree driver statements.  So it might mean that you need to provide your own DVI/VGA driver.  One way to verify is use Rpi3 to boot your VGA mon and then try Rpi4B.

Comment: Another thing is that I read the Rpi4B supports composite video (home TV like).  So if your VGA mon has composite video input, you try use it as a get around.  But I am not very sure of what I am saying, because I am only using HDMI mon for my Rpi4B now.

Answer (score 1):

this might help:

```
hdmi_drive=2
#config_hdmi_boost=4
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=47
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
disable_overscan=0
enable_tvout=0
```

credit to the poster at:
[Can a simple cable convert HDMI output to VGA?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/222/can-a-simple-cable-convert-hdmi-output-to-vga#231)

The only diff in my case is:

```
enable_tvout=0
```

with `enable_tvout=1` there was still no signal at monitor
And I found `config_hdmi_boost=4` was not needed.
The Adapter I used is not externally powered... I got this from amazon.ca
https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B00ZMV7RL2?ref=ppx_pt2_dt_b_prod_image

Comment: Exactly above settings helped me also, and i tried few different configurations before. I did connect my Pi 4 to VGA using HDMI switch, since i even didnt have the exact adapter - so now i hope it will work the same for the second Pi 4 of mine :)